# YML validation file is ignored

Tags: php, validation, symfony, yaml

I am new to the Symfony 2 web framework, and am struggling with a very basic validation task. I have an entity model `Post` that has a member `slug`, which I use to build the link to the post. In `Post.orm.yml` I defined `unique: true` and want to include this constraint as a validator as well.

I have created a file `validation.yml`:

```
# src/OwnBundles/BlogpostBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml

OwnBundles\BlogpostBundle\Entity\Post:
    properties:
        slug:
            - NotBlank: ~
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: slug
```

The creation function in my controller is quite simple:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();
    $form = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $post);

    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);
        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($post);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect(
                $this->generateUrl('own_bundles_blogpost_homepage')
            );
        }
    }
    return $this->render(
        'OwnBundlesBlogpostBundle:Default:add.html.twig',
        array(
            'title' => 'Add new blogpost',
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        )
    );
}
```

The basic pageflow works fine, I can add posts and see them, but if I duplicate a post title  to test my validation, it throws an exception: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'duplicate-slug' for key 'UNIQ_FAB8C3B3989D9B62'`. I have been scanning through documentation for quite some time now, but I was not able to find out why my `$form->isValid()` returns `true`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Did you enable validation in app/config/config.yml ?

```
...

framework:
    ...
    validation:    { enabled: true }
    ...

...
```

and if you want to define validation with annotations too, you have to both enable validation and annotation validation :

```
...

framework:
    ...
    validation:    { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true }
    ...

...
```

And then don't forget clear the `app/cache` directory.

Comment: my config.yml says: `framework: validation: { enable_annotations: true }`; i assumed this enables validation - and I was wrong... Thanks for the quick help, I don't know why I could not find this.

Comment: You have to use both parameters if you wanna use annotations too. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my config accordingly. Now it works like a charm.

Comment: I created an issue on github to make this more clear in the documentation of the Validation Component: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/4268

Comment: the symfony documentation only says "The Symfony validator is enabled by default"
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#book-validation-forms
WRONG ! bad symfony, bad ! :D

Comment: [Configuration reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#validation) says: "type: boolean default: true if form support is enabled, false otherwise"

Comment: I needed to clear cache after making validation folder and yml file. tnx

Comment: Are you using Idea/PHPStorm? In which case did you get completion on entity validating annotations?